# Remove class when clicked outside the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the HTML shown below, I want to display `input` after click on "ورود" and hide it when I click outside it's parent `<div>`.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="user-login-top">ورود</div>
 <div id="user-login-wrapper" class="">visible
   <input type="text" value="name">
 </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(function () {
    $("#user-login-top").on("click", function () {
       $("#user-login-wrapper").addClass("wide");
    });
    $(document).on("click", function (e) {
       if ($(e.target).is("#user-login-wrapper, #user-login-top") === false) {
           $("#user-login-wrapper").removeClass("wide");
        }
    });
});
```

here's my fiddle : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sadeghbayan/7f32byhn/9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.id != "user-login-top" && !$(e.target).closest("#user-login-wrapper").length) {
        $("#user-login-wrapper").removeClass("wide");
    }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f32byhn/16/)

---

Or If you can move `#user-login-top` to the parent of input you can simply do:

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest("#user-login-wrapper").length) 
        $("#user-login-wrapper").removeClass("wide");

});
```

Comment: @TJ closest wrap all the child ?

Comment: @Soheil It checks whether itself, or any of it's parents matches the selector...  [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)

Answer (score 2):

Well you have put the logic for all the targets except the text box that is wrapped in `user-login-wrapper`, So just add it with your logic and it works

**Example:**

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("#user-login-wrapper")==false 
        && $(e.target).is('#user-login-top')==false
        && $(e.target).is('#user-login-wrapper *')==false) {
        $("#user-login-wrapper").removeClass("wide");
    }
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7f32byhn/17/)

Comment: thx for your answer , but it's not just that an input , there are checkbox and two inputs and more ... in a parent div "#user-login-wrapper" , should i mention all of them in e.target or there is a better way ?

Comment: @user3642164, updated my answer with fiddle, you could achieve this via **$(e.target).is('#user-login-wrapper *')**